# <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions> in maven not working

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, assertion

here is my pom file portion where I used the  false property to disable all assertions in the tests. But it is still checking all assertion violations

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/JavaBeanNavigatorTest.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/JDOMNavigatorTest.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/XOMNavigatorTest.java</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*Tests.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this? Please give an example of a test and what you want to do with this test.

Comment: I want to disable the assertions in the unit test, so that it doesn't evaluate the results, for example, if I have this assertEquals(4, 5) in the test case and the assertions are disabled then it will not fail the test or throw assertion error, that's what I want.

Comment: <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions> is not disabling the assertions and assertion errors are still caught when I run mvn test

Comment: If you want to skip the tests, there are easier methods. Why do you want to specifically deactivate the assertions?

Comment: I dont want to skip test, I just want to disable assertions

Comment: So why do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

The [`enableAssertions`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#enableAssertions) setting controls Java [`assert`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html) statements, *not* JUnit assertions.

There's not a straightforward way to skip running JUnit assertions. You can use the [`testFailureIgnore`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) configuration to avoid failing the build due to test failures.